# Obtener valor de input en datatable y guardarlo en un array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, datatable

me gustaria ayuda con algo, necesito alamacenar el valor de un input puesto en datatables, obtengo valores de mi tabla y los tomo de manera buena, pero cuando agregue un input y quise tomar su valor no me funciono y el array arroja un String(0). me gustaria saber como puedo tomar todos los valores incluyendo el que inserto en el input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<?php include 'header.php' ?>

<body>
<div class="container shadow p-3 mt-5 bg-body rounded" style="background:#fff;">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length="2" id="tbl-buys">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>

    <br>
    <button id="btnObtener">Obtener</button>
</div>
</body>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

    let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
    let dt = $dt.DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "src/sql_consult/crud_crop.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                option: 4
            },
            dataSrc: "",
        },
        order: false,
        language: {
            url: "src/datatables/spanish.json"
        },
        columns: [{
                render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                    // ACA controlamos la propiedad para des/marcar el input
                    return "<input type='checkbox'" + (full.checked ? ' checked' : '') + "/>";
                },
                orderable: false
            },
            {
                data: 'idCultivo',
                orderable: false
            },
            {
                data: 'nombre',
                orderable: false
            },
            {
                data: 'descripcion',
                orderable: false
            },
            {
                data: null,
                render: function(data) {
                    
                    return "<input type='text' class='form-control w-25' id='cant'>";
                    
                },
            },
        ]
    });
    let $total = $('#total');

    // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
    $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function(evt) {
        let checked = this.checked;
        let total = 0;
        let data = [];
    
        dt.data().each(function(info) {
            // ACA cambiamos el valor de la propiedad
            info.checked = checked;
            // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
            if (info.checked) total += info.Precio;
            data.push(info);
        });

        dt.clear()
            .rows.add(data)
            .draw();
        $total.val(total);
    });

    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
        let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
        let total = parseFloat($total.val());
        // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
        info.checked = this.checked;
        let price = info.Precio;
        total += info.checked ? price : price * -1;
        $total.val(total);
    });


    // ACA suscribimos un listener
    $('#btnObtener').on('click', function() {
        let dt = $('#tbl-buys').DataTable();
        let checkeds = dt.data().toArray().filter((data) => data.checked);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'src/sql_consult/prueba.php',
            data: {
                checkeds: checkeds
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

            }
        })
    });


});
```

crud_crop.php

```
<?php 
include '../database/bd.php';

$id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
$nombre = (isset($_POST['nombre']))?$_POST['nombre']:'';
$description = (isset($_POST['description']))?$_POST['description']:'';
$status = (isset($_POST['status']))?$_POST['status']:'';
$option = (isset($_POST['option']))?$_POST['option']:'';

switch ($option) {

    case 1:
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo WHERE nombre= '$nombre' OR descripcion = '$description' ");
        if ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query) > 0) {
            $data = 0;
        
        }else {
            $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO cultivo (idCultivo,nombre,descripcion,estado)
            VALUES('$id','$nombre','$description','$status')");
            
            $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo ORDER BY idCultivo DESC LIMIT 1");
            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $data [] = $res;
                
            } 
        }
        break;
  
  
    case 2:
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo WHERE (nombre= '$nombre' AND idCultivo != '$id') OR (descripcion = '$description' AND idCultivo != '$id') ");
        if ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($query) > 0) {
            $data = 0;
        
        }else {
            $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE cultivo SET nombre='$nombre',descripcion='$description'WHERE idCultivo = $id ");

            $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo ORDER BY idCultivo DESC LIMIT 1");
            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $data [] = $res;
                    
            }   
            
        }
        break;
        

    
    case 3:

        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE cultivo SET estado= '0' WHERE idCultivo = $id");
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo");
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $data [] = $res;
        }  
        break;
  
    case 4:
        
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo WHERE estado = 1");
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $data [] = $res;
        }  
        
        break;
    
    case 5: 
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo WHERE estado = 0");
        $data = array();
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            if (!empty($res)) {
                $data [] = $res;
            }else {
                $data['data'][] = null;
            }
        }  
        
        break;
        
    case 6: 
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE cultivo SET estado= '1' WHERE idCultivo = $id");
        $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM cultivo");
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $data [] = $res;
        }  
        break;
}
print json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

prueba.php

```
<?php 
include '../database/bd.php';
$array = (isset($_POST['checkeds']))?$_POST['checkeds']:'';
var_dump($array);
 ?>
```

Bien, si se fijan envio checkeds, pues ahi se almacenaron todos los valores, pero como mencione anteriormente menos el del input, quite las lineas de codigo donde intente agregar el input porque no servian y no conozco mucho de este tipo de datatables que es con checkbox.
Inserto una imagen donde estoy haciendo "pruebas".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Porque incluyes el header.php y el footer.php y el script fuera de sus elementos "naturales"?  Entiendo que el header.php debe ir **antes** del cierre del `</head>` y el footer.php y el script antes del cierre del `</body>`.  Ya se que no tiene que ver con la respuesta que esperas, pero pinta que estan mal puestos y puedes obtener resultados imprevisibles según el navegador que los interprete seguramente.

Comment: Gracias por la observacion, crees que podrias ayudarme con la consulta que plantee?, por favor.

Comment: Eso espero, pero necesito un par de registros de ejemplo de lo que te devuelve `src/sql_consult/crud_crop.php`

Comment: Me devuelve lo que ves en la tabla, lo del input es lo que inserte y lo que necesito es tomar ese valor y agregralo al checkeds, para asi enviarlo a traves de preuba.php y tomar sus valores para posteriormente insertarlo en una tabla en una base de datos.

Comment: Verlo lo veo, pero si tengo que teclearlo me pides demasiado :-)   Debes facilitarnos el trabajo porque no somos tan aplicados ni tenemos tanto tiempo.  Necesito el json_encode o el array de lo que te devuelve crud_crop.php para realizar mis pruebas locales.

Comment: Listo, como podria enviarte eso?

Comment: Agregalo al final de la pregunta simplemente, así otros también podran colaborar en la respuesta si a mi no me sale bien

Comment: Ya lo hice, quiero explicarle que esto es una prueba, lo pienso usar con otro archivo, pero puse ese porque estaba practicando para luego poder implementarlo.

Comment: Bueno, no me referia a el código del crud_crop.php, sino a su salida... es decir, un `print_r($data)` al final del archivo o bien, al ser ajax te va a costar verlo, un `file_put_contents('salida.txt', print_r($data, true));` al final del archivo, para que te cree un nuevo archivo llamado `salida.txt` en la misma carpeta donde esté el crud_crop.php y lo puedas abrir y copiar y pegar el resultado en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionarlo podrías intentar estos cambios:

1. Donde pones esto:

```
{
    data: null,
    render: function(data) {
        return "<input type='text' class='form-control w-25' id='cant'>";
    },
},
```

ponle un nombre en lugar del **null**, por ejemplo, `cant`:

```
{
    data: 'cant',
    render: function(data) {
        return "<input type='text' class='form-control w-25' id='cant'>";
    },
},
```

2. Donde pones esto:

```
    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
```

agrégale un filtro más para que no se confunda con los otros inputs de `cant`:

```
    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
```

3. Luego agrégale una clase a los inputs del `cant`, por ejemplo, **`cant`**, de este modo, quitándole el **id='cant'** porque se duplica en cada línea y no lo vamos a usar en esta solución, y agrégale un `value='0'`:

```
return "<input type='text' class='form-control w-25 cant' value='0'>";
```

4. Y por último, pon a la escucha los cambios realizados en ese input con esa clase para que se actualice el `cant`:

```
    $dt.on( 'change', '.cant', function () {
        dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().cant = $(this).val()
    } );
```

Con esto ya deberías poder enviar correctamente los datos a **prueba.php**.

Comment: Entendi los demas cambios, pero el paso 4, es una nueva linea de codigo, o debo colocarla dentro de alguna que ya tenia? pq la puse fuera de las que tenia y me sale que cant no esta definido, ya me cuenta, lo que sucede es que en {data: cant}, ese data no existe cuando lo trae de crud_crop, pq ese es un input al cual le quiero poner una cantidad y luego hacer checked y que se envie junto a los demas valores de esa fila que traje + el input al cual le puse un valor. Espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Hice el cambio que le dije en vez de {data: cant}, lo deje como {data:null} y ya tomo el valor, muchas gacias, como siempre me ayudas, eres el mejor bro.

Comment: vale, no se porque no te funcionaba con el {data: cant} (seguramente porque no lo puse entre comillas simples como los demás), pero era mi forma de inicializar esa propiedad, aunque por lo que has descubierto tu mismo (y yo no sabia) no hacia falta y la crea cuando hace esto seguramente: `dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().cant = $(this).val()`.  En mis pruebas también funcionaba con el {data: 'cant'} (entre comillas), aunque ahora veo que no era necesario.

Comment: Una consulta, y si yo tuviera un campo de "precio" que traigo de la base y quisiera multiplicarlo con la cantidad que inserto, para que en otro input se coloque el total, todo dentro del mismo datatable, como seria ?

Comment: A ver, a ciegas es dificil decirte como hacerlo, además no comparto la idea de usar un input para el subtotal, pues deberia ser solo texto (los campos calculados no deben después pasarse con formulario al backend, porque pueden ser manipulados en el frontend, es mejor tan solo pasar codigo + cantidad y en el backend volver a calcularlo).  Siendo así, la fórmula, dentro del on change de .cant, podria ser esta: `subtotal = parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat(dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().precio)` y luego `$(this).parent().next().html(subtotal);` para mostrarlo en la columna siguiente