# Planteamiento datatable con respecto a una operacion entre columna e input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Necesito que se multiplique el valor de la columna costo por la cantidad que ingreso en el input y luego se coloque automaticamente en el input que esta en la columna total, adjunto el codigo que tengo como posible referencia, muchas gracias.
Si necesitan algun archivo o informacion extra, yo ire editando conforme necesiten algun archivo o alguna consulta con respecto al tema.

```
//INSUMOS
let dt2 = $("#tableInsumos").DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "src/sql_consult/crud_mix.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      option: 3,
    },
    dataSrc: "",
  },

  language: {
    url: "src/datatables/spanish.json",
  },
  columns: [
    {
      render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
        // ACA controlamos la propiedad para des/marcar el input
        return (
          "<input type='checkbox'" + (full.checked ? " checked" : "") + "/>"
        );
      },
      orderable: false,
    },
    {
      data: "idInsumos",
      orderable: false,
    },
    {
      data: "nombre",
      orderable: false,
    },
    {
      data: "descripcion",
      orderable: false,
    },
    {
      data: "precioUnitario",
      orderable: false,
    },
    {
      data: "cant",
      render: function (data) {
        return "<input type='text' class='form-control w-25 cant' value='0'>";
      },
    },
    {
      data: null,
      render: function (data) {
        //'cantAdd_" +data.idInsumos +"'
        return "<input type='text' id='total' class='form-control w-50 total'  value='0' disabled>";
      },
    },
  ],
  
});

$("#tableInsumos .cant").keyup(function () {
  let total = 0;
  row = $(this).closest("tr"); //devuelve el antepasado
  precio = parseInt(row.find("td:eq(4)").text()); //busca un descendiente
  //Captura la posición de la columna en la que se está haciendo el cambio
  let index = $(this).parents("tr").find(".cant").index(this);

  //Captura el valor que hay en cada celda
  $("table tbody tr").each(function (i, row) {
    let cantidad = $(row).find("td").eq(index + 1).find(".cant").val();
    //Si el valor es numérico se hace la suma para evitar que muestre NaN en el total cuando las cantidades estén vacías
    if ($.isNumeric(parseFloat(cantidad))) {
      total = parseInt(precio) + parseInt(cantidad);
    }
  });
  //Se asigna la suma al total correspondiente
  $(".total").eq(index).html(total);
});
```

Como se aprecia en la foto necesito ejemplo que en cantida poner 10 y que se multiplique por el costo que es 50 y que ese valor que seria 500 se ponga en total de manera automatica y asi sucesivamente en caso de que cambie la cantidad

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te sugerí en un comentario a [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/538645/263200) en una pregunta anterior, yo lo haria así:

```
$("#tableInsumos").on('keyup', '.cant', function() {
  let subtotal = parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat(dt2.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().precioUnitario)
  $(this).parent().next().find(".total").val(subtotal);
});
```

Fíjate que ponemos a la escucha el evento `keyup` sobre la clase `cant` de la tabla con id **tableInsumos**.

Luego calculamos la múltiplicacion del valor del elemento input con la clase **cant** referenciado con `$(this).val()` por el valor de la columna `precioUnitario` de datatable, referenciada con `dt2.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().precioUnitario`, y todo eso lo asignamos a la variable **subtotal**.

Y a continuación, partiendo del input con clase `cant` que ha lanzado el evento **this**, convertido a objeto jquery mediante **$(this)**, aprovechamos las funciones **parent()** para salirnos del input y llegar a la definición de columna actual **td**, y desde allí nos dirigimos a la siguente con **next()**, donde se encuentra el input con la clase **total**, que encontramos desde allí mediante **find(".total")**, y al cual tan solo nos queda cambiarle el valor usando **val()** asignándole el subtotal calculado previamente, es decir, con **val(subtotal)**.